# Spelling Alternatives for Lithuanian Surnames

Tags: surnames, lithuania

I am having trouble with determining the correct surname spelling for my grandfather. On almost every document, including those from Churches, the names have been spelled different. Examples: Mike Versieckis, Mateus Varsackas, Michael Matthew (Matus) Varsackas, Wersieckis, Verseckas, Varsoki, Versocky, Atari, and so on. On each document, I have determined by the extraneous information given that matches my ancestor, that each person is my grandfather.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can tell which surname is correctly spelled?

How would I contact anyone from Vilnius, Lithuania without the correct spelling?

I have deepened my research in Ancestry DNA matches. There are hundreds of matches from 4th - 8th generation, but no matches as1st - 3rd generations. These are on my father's side of the family. On my mothers side, Robinson, I have found literally thousands of close matches.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better; my mother-in-law's grandparents names were spelled seven different ways on seven different voting lists in Manitoba. (So, the same agency, re-verifying names from an existing list, got a different spelling *every single time*)

Comment: There was a similar question (https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/finding-an-immigrant-ancestors-origin-from-lithuania) that might help you?

Comment: The closest match I was able to find was in https://www.scribd.com/doc/53134621/10-000-Lithuanian-Last-Names-and-Surnames and was "Vasaukas".

Comment: Your question seems written to assume that there was a single "correct" spelling of your grandfather's surname during his whole life, but that's probably not true. For instance, depending on who was in control of a place, they tended to record names in ways that fit with their language; you can see this in surnames which have been changed to look more "Lithuanian" in some eras. Surnames were probably also re-spelled to sound more Polish or Russian at various places/times. Your grandfather may have been comfortable with such changes and considered more than one as "correct".